# What authtype value to pass to X509TrustManager checkServerTrusted function

Tags: android

On Android platform the X509TrustManager class has a checkServerTrusted function. This function is defined as follows

```
     public abstract void checkServerTrusted (X509Certificate[] chain, String authType)
```

I will be using this to verify chain of certificates sent by TLS server. According to the docs

authType = the key exchange algorithm name

but I have not found any examples of what value to pass here for TLS

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It so happens that Android ignores the `authType` parameter outright. Unfortunately, the API is old and established, so the parameter can not be omitted. Documentation is not helpful either, implying that the parameter might be of use, even though it's not.

Citing a chromium developer https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=627154#c1

> This was the official recommendation of the Android team (and as an API has, unfortunately, 'rusted shut' due to third-parties).

> I agree that it's not inconceivable that the Android team may decide to break this in the future, but that's a significant break, especially considering Android can't really check key usages given its environment constraints.

As far as I can tell the present established practice is to pass the string "RSA" always.

Comment: This answer was surprisingly difficult to get by, especially considering that certificate validity checking is a relatively common thing to do.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an Android developer, but general Java. However for standalone Java you should use probably sun.security.validator.Validator.VAR.* constants. For my testing code sun.security.validator.Validator.VAR_GENERIC looks ok.

Comment: It looks that from Java 7 some_update sun proprietary API is no longer available, so you need to use just "generic" string

Comment: did you get the answer?